# Move a shape inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have the following list of lists representing a matrix:

```
space = [ 
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

The number 1s represent an upside down L (like a gamma, "Γ"). How can I make this "object" move to the right, left, up and down as if it was a block? I move it with "asdw" keys.

**Important:** I am not able to use `numpy`, so thats makes the work way more difficult.

This is my failed method to make a RIGHT direction movement (btw it doesnt make the movement correctly), but i dont think its the best way and dont really think I can escalate it to other movements:

```
def show_space(space):
    for line in space:
        print(line)

x = input("Movement: ")

if x == 'd':
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if space[i][j] == 1:
                try:
                    if space[i][j+1] == 0:
                        space[i][j] = 0
                        space[i][j+1] = 1
                    if space[i][j+1] == 1 and space[i][j+2] == 0:
                        space[i][j] = 0
                        space[i][j+2] = 1
                except IndexError:
                    pass

show_space(space)
```

Is there any other method I could try? Or correct the one Im using? Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The gamma not only should be able to move right up down left, it should also be able to move 90 degrees, mirror itself, and all possible shapes that form can take. So if i had to hardcode all possible gamma or L combinations, i would have to hardcode 48 possibilities. I dont know wether hardcoding that is the optimal way to be honest.

Im not saying hardcoding the postions is not acceptable, it could definitely be a solution, but I just dont feel like its the correct way. i may be wrong of course.

What do you think?

Comment: in the given list the matrix form an "L", not a gamma

Comment: @j1-lee yes, i just found out i cannot use ```numpy```

Comment: @cards thanks for pointing that out. Corrected

Comment: what happen if you move it to right, after the "end" of the matrix? not allowed or cycle to the other side?

Comment: @cards It should not be allowed to cycle to the other side. And one thing i have to clarify to the users who propose me to hardcode all the possible positions of the gamma: The gamma not only should be able to move right up down left, it should also be able to move 90 degrees, mirror itself, and all possible shapes that form can take. So if i had to hardcode all possible gamma or L combinations, i would have to hardcode 48 possibilities. And I dont think its the best way tbh.

Comment: Do any of the keys also rotate or mirror the shape? Or is asdw only for ordinal (up down left right) directions and that's all?

Comment: @Cole Yes, asdw are just for odinal (up down left right), then I thought about adding special characters to do those rotations and mirrors

Comment: By adding rotation and flipping, you introduce a *lot* of difficulty. For instance, what is the pivot point for a 90° rotation? Is it the corner? Is it the spot inside the corner? Is it one of the ends of the shape? If I'm not mistaken, you can recover all orientations just from composing horizontal flips, vertical flips, and the transpose. I think you need to spend some time thinking about what you're trying to do (and why you are constraining yourself to no imports, even standard library imports). This smells like homework, so I've left a partial solution in my edited answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd suggest doing something like this:

Calculate all the indices for each gamma shape in the matrix, kept stored in a dictionary with the each corner index tuple as the dictionary keys, then whenever the corner moves, figure out the indices that should be 1s, and assign to a copy of a matrix of zeros.

```py
positions = {(0, 0): ((0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)),
             (0, 1): ((0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1)),
             (0, 2): ((0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)),
             (1, 0): ((1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0)),
             (1, 1): ((1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1)),
             (1, 2): ((1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2))}


def move_gamma(corner):
    board = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
    try:
        for (i, j) in (corner, *positions[corner]):
            board[i][j] = 1
        return board
    except KeyError:
        print("You can't move there!")
        return board


def flip_h(board):
    return [[*reversed(row)] for row in board]


def flip_v(board):
    return [*reversed(board)]


def transpose(board):
    return [[*t] for t in zip(*board)]
```

Demo:

```py
In [3]: board = move_gamma((1, 1))

In [4]: print(*board, sep="\n")
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]

In [5]: board = move_gamma((1, 2))

In [6]: print(*board, sep="\n")
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]

In [7]: print(*transpose(board), sep="\n")
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Just a heads up, you'd still need to implement the logic for mapping WASD to movement relative to the current corner indices.

Comment: The gamma not only should be able to move right up down left, it should also be able to move 90 degrees, mirror itself, and all possible shapes that form can take. So if i had to hardcode all possible gamma or L combinations, i would have to hardcode 48 possibilities. I forgot to mention that on the question, and I dont know wether hardcoding that is the optimal way to be honest. What do you think?

Comment: Do you plan on supporting multiple different sized boards? Is there some reason why (while tedious) hardcoding the positions is not acceptable? Please edit the original post to include your new requirements.

Comment: its just a 4x4 sized board. Im not saying hardcoding the postions is not acceptable, it could definitely be a solution, but I just dont feel like its the correct way. i may be wrong of course @ddejohn

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stay within the confines of the standards library, you can use [`collection.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), which has a [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method that does exactly what you need and will have to implement in lists if you can't use deque.

This is what I can offer with deque.

NB. this wraps around the edges which might not be intended,

```py
from collections import deque

space = deque([
    deque([0, 1, 1, 0]),
    deque([0, 0, 1, 0]),
    deque([0, 0, 1, 0]),
    deque([0, 0, 0, 0]),
    ])

def move(mvt):
    if mvt == "s":
        space.rotate(1)
    elif mvt == "w":
        space.rotate(-1)
    elif mvt == "d":
        [x.rotate(1) for x in space]
    elif mvt == "a":
        [x.rotate(-1) for x in space]
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

move("d")  # etc
```

Comment: This is a great solution, although it does allow for "wrapping" around each edge to the opposite edge. Not sure if OP wants that, but probably best to point it out explicitly.

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to use these libraries that make the work easier. I have to manage the movement just with the tools python offers from scratch. I dont know if you understand what im trying to explain. And yes, the shape should not cycle to the other side @ddejohn

Comment: This module is in the standard library, just like lists and strings, so it's fair game in my mind. But if you really only can use lists, then write a rotate function for lists and use it same as above. edit: I just saw your edit above, these are many calculations you need to make, without wrapping, doing it without a single import is going to be *very* hard work.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question - instead of keeping track of all space (array with mostly `0`s), use an `object` (python `dict`) to instead specify the shape, and where to start drawing it e.g.:

```py
{ 
  'abs_pos': (0,1),
  'rel_points': [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (2,0)]
}
```

Then moving it only amounts to updating the location of (e.g.) the upper-left corner `abs_pos`.

When it's time to print your map of all space, start from `abs_pos` and then add a dot at each point in `rel_points`.